# How to get the exact match of a string in file using FIND or FINDSTR in dos

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, findstr

I am trying to get the exact match of a path ("\Users\sachin.a.goyal\Desktop\test\") which is there in a file:

```
 Biggest.txt:
 1 number: 
 name = DMS 3.0 R2 - Deployment Workbook_APAC v4_WMT 
 size = 15634835 
 path = \Users\sachin.a.goyal\Desktop\test\ 
 2 number: 
 name = Scenarios 
 size = 254 
 path = \Users\sachin.a.goyal\Desktop\test\New folder\
```

I am using this command:

```
 findstr /x /c:"\Users\sachin.a.goyal\Desktop\test\" Biggest.txt
```

But after this command, DOS window is stucked. It is not giving any error but looks like it is expecting some other parameter. Please help.

Comment: Which operating system? It _could_ be MS-DOS, but it is most likely just the command prompt in Windows [something]. I'm tagging the post "Windows" for the time being. If it explicitly is MS-DOS, feel free to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /x is not going to work as the entire line needs to match the search string, and in this case, it is prefixed with `path =`.  Also, the `\` symbols need to be escaped so they are not interpreted as commands.  Finally, regular expression mode will help capture the right line, as it ends in a space then the end of line - the end of line can be represented as a `$`:

```
H:\>findstr /r /c:"\\Users\\sachin.a.goyal\\Desktop\\test\\ *$" biggest.txt
path = \Users\sachin.a.goyal\Desktop\test\
```

The reason for your search hanging is probably one of the `\` was matching a command.

If you are using a variable to hold the path being searched for, you would still need to escape the backslashes.  You can do this with the replace feature:

```
set path="c:\Users\sachin.a.goyal\Desktop\test\"
set path=%path:\=\\%
echo path
c:\\Users\\sachin.a.goyal\\Desktop\\test\\
```

The second line says, replace all backslahes with double backslashes.  Unfortunately I don't have a Windows box to test on right now, but you may need to escape the backslashes still:

```
    set path=%path:\\=\\\\%
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!It worked. But The actual problem is that I have stored the path in a variable and I am matching the value of that variable in file. Then I have to save the path in the variable as you told with regular expression '\' ?

Comment: Yeah that should be fine - are you still getting stuck with the backslashes?

Comment: Yes....that variable contains the path with single backslashes only

Comment: Can you test it by populating the var with double backslashes and if it works we'll figure a way to fix it

Comment: Yes it works when populate the var like that `code` set var = \\Users\\sachin.a.goyal\\Desktop\\test\\ *$

Comment: Now can u help me please how will I change the path stored in the variable as regular expression

Comment: Updated answer with variable escaping